# Why there are wrinkles on my isosurface rendered by pov-ray?

Tags: povray

I'm beginner of pov-ray, and I'm trying to use it to render some wavefunction from my simulation.

I tried the following code, but why there are wrinkles on the surface?

```
#include "colors.inc"

camera{location  <10,10,-10>  look_at 0}
light_source{ <20,20,-10> White }

#declare P=function{internal(53)}; 
#declare P0=P(1,3,0,2);

isosurface {
    function{(x,y,z,0)} 
    contained_by { box { -8, 8 } }
    texture{pigment{Red}}
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that's because of a too low max_gradient value.

> "My isosurface is not rendering properly: there are holes or random
>   noise or big parts or even the whole isosurface just disappears." The
>   most common reason for these type of phenomena with isosurfaces is a
>   too low max_gradient value. Use evaluate to make POV-Ray calculate a
>   proper max_gradient for the isosurface (remember to specify a sensible
>   max_gradient even when you use evaluate or else the result may not be
>   correct).

If we increase the max_gradient, we can get a good result:

```
#include "colors.inc"

camera{location  <10,10,-10>  look_at 0}
light_source{ <20,20,-10> White }

#declare P=function{internal(53)}; 
#declare P0=P(1,3,0,2);
#declare Min_factor= 0.6;
isosurface {

    function{P(x,y,z,0)} 
    evaluate 213.6, 1.29, 0.7    //this set the max_gradient
    contained_by { box { -8, 8 } }
    texture{pigment{Green}}
}
```

[image]